# How to add date to a file's name using UNLOAD in Redshift

Tags: sql, date, amazon-redshift, filenames, unload

I found 2 solutions:

1. Using AWS Data Pipeline to schedule the query (Unload) and use 's3://reporting-team-bucket/importfiles/test_123-#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd-HH')}.csv'
2. writing an MV command to rename the file on the s3 bucket

Is there a way to give a file's the current date by **only** using Redshift, with no other services?

Here is my code so far:

```
unload
(
'select * from table'
)
to 's3://bucket/unload_test/test_123_{CurrentDate}.gz'
ACCESS_KEY_ID '12345678910'
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY '10987654321'
GZIP
PARALLEL off;
```

Just need to get CurrentDate to be 202106 for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey — you can try normal string concatenation probably: `'s3://bucket/unload_test/test_123_' || TRUNC(GETDATE()) || 'gz'`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work (i wish it did). you cannot exit the ' ' when you type the file name. If you leave it inside it, the name of the file will literally be "test_123_'|| trunc(GETDATE()) ||'gz".

Comment: What tool is issuing the SQL?  The simplest method is often to have the issuer give SQL with the filename already containing the date.

Comment: @BillWeiner Not sure if this is what you asked, but I am using DBeaver to query the SQL.
Can you elaborate on what you mean by "have the issuer give SQL with the filename already containing the date"? Thanks!

Comment: DBeaver (like most benches) support client side scripting and variables (but I'm not a DBeaver user).  You can set bench variables and use them in queries -  like: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2563

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried using `UNLOAD` in a transaction, but if it works, you could use a procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Redshift unload gives an option to load the data in a by partition. Use `**PARTITION BY(COLUMN_NAME)**`. Here is an example

```
unload (' 

        SELECT   col1
               , col2
               , col3
               , current_date as partition_by_me
         FROM dummy
         
 '
 )
to 's3://mybucket/dummy/'
partition by(partition_by_me)
iam_role 'arn of IAM role'
kms_key_id 'arn of kms key'
encrypted
FORMAT AS PARQUET
```

In the above example, Added a dummy column `partition_by_me` as current_date. Used that in the unload command `partition by(parition_by_me)`. Data in S3 lands in that specific partition.

S3 path would be : `s3://mybucket/dummy/partition_by_me=2022-08-18/000.parquet` Timestamp with zone does work with this.

*** Dummy column does not get exported to S3 file as an additional column, unless you want to include. Following clause need to used to include in the unloaded data set.

`partition by(partition_by_me) INCLUDE`

`INCLUDE` clause will include the column in exported data sets.